# Add .htaccess file outside the Laravel public

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

please I added a .htaccess file outside the public folder in the Laravel 9 project without copying or removing all files from the public to the project folder. Code for the .htaccess is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
    RewriteRule ^.env - [F,L,NC]

</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

the .htaccess worked okay on Laravel 7 and 8 instead of Laravel 9. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

is likely causing the issue if that file doesn't exist - that file was [deleted](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/583281c4090ea89c7426853e0bae1151e7abc253) in Laravel 9 and moved within the framework.  Adding it back (e.g. if you had customizations) [shouldn't cause any issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40034), or (not tested) you can try updating it to `public/index.php` as suggested in the comment below.

Comment: You can't simply remove that line, you need to replace it with something. Perhaps it should be rewriting to `index.php` instead? Although the OP talks of using this file _outside_ of the public folder, so maybe this rule is not needed at all, or rewriting to `public/index.php`?